# How do I configure OpenVPN as a Gateway client for Witopia?

Tags: routing, vpn, tunneling

I have the following setup:

- Witopia SSL account
- Synology 409 NAS (with OpenVPN and Apache etc)
- PS3
- Mac
- Apple AirPort router (configured for NAT)
- Locked IPT-box (using DHCP and NAT traversing)

```
Internet
|
Router (192.168.0.1)
|
|--NAS
|--Mac
|--PS3
|--IPT-box
```

Requirements:

1. The NAS should handle the VPN connection with Witopia.
2. All connections originating outside the Router and who are routed to the NAS or Mac should reach its target. Nothing originating from outside should enter the VPN tunnel.
3. All connections that originates behind the router and are "aimed specificly" at the NAS should reach it and not be hijacked by the VPN tuinnel.(NFS, SBM, HTTP etc.)
4. Connections that originates from applications on the NAS and terminates anywhere outside the router should go through the VPN tunnel.
5. All connections from PS3 that terminates outside router should go through the tunnel. Connections from PS3 to NAS (SMB, NFS, DLNA etc) should not go through the tunnel, but be served by the NAS.
6. All connections to and from the IPT-box should go direct via the router, not the tunnel.

Is this possible with the hardware that I already have? How and where should I configure it?

/BE

Comment: What OSes do the NAS and router do? This is a huge question, I suggest you break it down into at least two, one about configuring the NAS and one for the router.

Comment: The NAS is a Synology specific Linux with kernel 2.6.32.12 that is using the dd-wrt ipkg repository, so I guess they are quite similar. The router has some kind of proprietary OS. Not possible to add software to it. Only to configure port forwards and similar. From Apple "NAT, DHCP, PPPoE, VPN Passthrough (IPSec, PPTP, and L2TP), DNS Proxy, SNMP, IPv6 (6to4 and manual tunnels)". I agree that the question would be more manageable if I broke it down. I just don't know enough to know where to draw the line between different questions. That requires at least a rough idea about how to solve it.

Comment: A thought: Would it be easier if I bought a cheap DD-WRT compatible router and used it as a dedicated VPN Gateway? I was looking at D-Link DIR-300 wich is really cheap but sounds to be good enough. It doesn't have VLAN support. Will that matter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Astrill on my DD-WRT router. This was so easy to setup and Astrill has VPN servers in more than 25 countries. This is their demo video "How to setup OpenVPN on DD-WRT" - https://www.astrill.com/public/DDWRT-Setup2.mp4 I think you can ask them for a free trial to make sure it works OK on your hardware.

But if you have Witopia account already, it's better to contact their support and they should help you.

Comment: Witopia don't give support for other software (or hardware) than their own.